# Aggregate values from properties in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I want to somehow count the outgoing edges' properties that are integers and make sure that I return only nodes with this count above `100`. How could it be done in `Neo4j`?

Right now I am stuck with the following query:

```
MATCH (cl:Cluster {clusterId:'1'})-[r:CONTAINS]->(c:Cell)
WHERE (c)-[:EXPRESSES {expr:x}]->()
RETURN cl,c
```

One `Cell` can have many outgoing `EXPRESSES` edges with the associated integer properties. I need to loop over all of the edges of every `Cell` and return only `Cells` that have total sum over all of their edges `> 100`.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are trying to: (a) count the number of properties that have integer values, (b) get the sum of a specific integer property, (c) get the sum of all integer properties, or get something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
MATCH (cl:Cluster {clusterId:'1'})-[:CONTAINS]->(c:Cell)-[r:EXPRESSES]->()
WITH cl, c, sum(r.expr) as sum
WHERE sum > 100
RETURN cl, c
```

The `sum()` aggregation is grouped per cl and c, then it's just a matter of using WHERE to only keep rows where the sum is over 100.